# Remove/change the "Ask a question" in the search popover overlay on top of the page

Tags: feature-request, search

When you click in the search field at the top of every page, you get shown some extra information for searching. It includes a brief explanation about the search syntax as well as link to show more. However, it also includes a button that leads you to ask a question.

When searching I expect to *avoid* asking a question by finding the answer first. Even if I do decide to make a question, there is a different button on top of the page that will leads to the question interface.

So, a lot of times searching and asking are not related. When they *are* (because you're looking for prior relevant questions but can't find any), I do not think the "Ask a question" is not needed in the search form. Including screenshots to illustrate this:

[image: Image showing the search bar and the "Ask question" button on a normal page]

[image: Image showing the search popover that has a "Ask a question" button and a "search help" clickable link at the bottom]

Removing the button seems like it would alleviate the problem but it might be even better to change it to an actual search button which is also missing:

[image: Image showing the "Ask a question" button changed to "Search"]