# My hat falls off when editing tags with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts, inline-tag-editor

I noticed this when fiddling around on one of my questions.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a question (this one), and use the <kbd>T</kbd> (10k only) shortcut to open the tag editor.
2. Add any tag (although the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) one is preferred), click "Save Edits", let it give you the error, then cancel it.
3. Watch your hat fall off!

[image]

I also did this on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357281/announcing-a-design-experiment-re-placement-of-ask-question-button) post, and accidentally pulled Anita's hairdo off.  With apologies to Anita, can we fix that?

Comment: There aren't very many comments on this post yet, so [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdHzc.png) is what it should look like (no hat).  If it doesn't, assume my hat is now in this comment.

Comment: Or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ylH.png).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357935/369802 ?